# IIS Hosted WCF service does not recycle TCP ports "Insufficient winsock resources"

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF Service hosted on IIS 7 that runs successfully for a period of time, then fails to communicate to other network locations ( I suspect there are no TCP ports available to connect to the outside world )

**Background of application:**

My system transcodes large media files ( which takes time). I have a centrally hosted WCF service which is is located on server A - which will be referred to as 'Central WCF Service'. I then have many client services which do the actual transcoding of the media files on different servers: B,C,D,E,F and so on - which will be referred to as 'Client Processor services'. The Central WCF Service manages which Client Processor Service the 'Transcode Jobs' get sent to be processed . Each of these Client Processor Services is a self hosted WCF service, they basically  do the long running process, and get polled by the Central WCF Service checking job progress percentage. The Central WCF service therefore opens up a lot of connections to these clients to poll them for their job progresss, polling occurs roughly once every 2-3 seconds to each of the clients.

The Central WCF service stores a string list of the addresses for the Client Processor services. The code which Is used to poll each client is descrbied below ( stripped down version ):

```
public ClientProcessorClient getClientByaddress(string address)
{
    Binding bidning = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    return new ClientProcessorClient(bidning, new EndpointAddress(address));
}

public void pollJobs()
{
    foreach (string clientAddress in clients)
    {
        ClientProcessorClient client = getClientByaddress(clientAddress);
        int progress = client.GetProgress();
        client.Close();
        // Do stuff with progress
    }
}
```

**What happens when it breaks:**

I can submit many transcode jobs to the Central WCF Service and it submits jobs to the clients successfully updating progress etc. After around an hour of processing the server that the Central WCF service is hosted on stops working properly. Errors are thrown by the Central WCF Service `Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation.` when trying to contact the Client WCF services. The Client WCF services are all pingable from a WCF Test Client running on my local machine. Also I have noticed that when in this state the server cannot view network file resources - I have logged in remotely and tried to locate a network attached storage folder, it fails to connect. I CAN however make calls TO that server e.g. I can open a WCF Test Client and connect to the Central WCF Service and call it's ping methods. Communications are allowed IN but not OUT from the server.

**Few points of interest:**

In the faulted state the connections TO the server can be made, but not FROM the server.

Each of my services ( Central WCF service and Client Processor Service ) are singleton instances.

The Central WCF Service is hosted in IIS 7 and application pool Recycling is disabled

Unfortunately named pipe is not an option ( the clients and servers are on different machines )

**My thoughts/Questions**

All signs point towards the server running out of TCP sockets. Am I setting up the WCF `ClientProcessorClient`'s properly? Am I disposing of them properly? Do I need to wrap them in a `using` statement? Does anybody know how I can debug/diagnose where the problem occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For good or ill, Microsoft decided to implement the WCF service proxy logic (either ClientBase or directly from ChannelFactory) to allow exceptions to be thrown in the Close() method. I believe all the Dispose() method does is call Close() but I have never tried to look at the source code. If a proxy is in a faulted state, Abort() must be called to release resources (such as TCP sessions).

The implication is the WCF service proxy does not release resources until a call to either Close() or Abort() completes successfully. Take a look at this [blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) for one option to properly closing the proxy instance.

Comment: I will test this soon, although I am pretty sure that the `Close()` is actually succeeding every time, thus there 'should' be no sockets left open based on what you have just said.